# fetch xml CRM report on SQL Reporting Server

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Is this possible upload a fetch XML rdl report to use with SQL Reporting server
The report would display fine in BIDs but when i upload it to the SQL reporting server.
I get the following error

> **An error occurred during client rendering. An error has occurred
>   during report processing. An attempt has been made to use a data
>   extension 'MSCRMFETCH' that is either not registered for this report
>   server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.**

When i go to Data sources section of the report I got this error

> **The data processing extension used for this report is not available.
>   It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly.**

Is displaying FetchXML report possible with SQL Reporting server 2008?
Is there a plug-in or update that I can install where I will be able to select CRM as my data source?

Here is the error code I am getting from Sql Server 
An error occurred during client rendering.
An error has occurred during report processing.
An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'MSCRMFETCH' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services

When I go to the properties -> data sources of the report
I go this error next to the data source
The data processing extension used for this report is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly.

Thanks

Comment: take a look here http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/crm/thread/1a1e3712-2fcf-46a1-93a7-5fe1ecb3d282 Looks like the extensions need to be installed on the server

Comment: I actually have problems displaying reports in CRM so i install that extension which fixed the problem, but I still can not run the fetchxml report off SQL reporting server.

Comment: Will the report not run (i.e., gives an error) or does it run but just not return data/display anything? Is there any filtering setup in the FetchXML?

Comment: There is no filter setup for the report. I can actually run the report on the BIDs but when i upload the rdl to reporting server i got those error.

Comment: @Nicknow would you know a reason for the report showing NO DATA in crm online whereas showing plenty of data within VIsual Studio?

Comment: @Nobe123, Did the issue end up being just due to no filter being setup?   By that I mean, did the original error when you went to the "Data Sources" section disappear?  I know this was on an SQL Reporting server, but did you have an On-Premise or Online version of CRM?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a FetchXML report in SQL Reporting Services except via the CRM application - i.e., you cannot launch the report directly from SQL Reporting Services.

You must deploy the report through Dynamics CRM and run the report from Dynamics CRM.